# Missing Character For KeyEvent

Tags: java, char, keylistener, keyevent

When using the `KeyTyped` method for the `KeyListener`, sometimes I get "missing characters". I'll show the code I use to get them, then ask my question.

```
public class KeyInput implements KeyListener
{
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
     {
         System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
     }
}
```

I left out a few required methods because they are unrelated to my question. If I press a letter, it prints the letter to console. But if I use a key combination, ie. **control** **+** **g**, The character printed to console is just a square with a question mark.

[image]

Is there a way to detect if the character is a "missing character"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `canDisplay(...)` method of the `Font` class.